# Third party terminals not working for some commands

Tags: terminal

I tried to use nvm but found that the nvm command is not found but I can use nvm with the default Linux Terminal [Hyper not working screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erTM2.png) I don't know what the issue is
I have the latest hyper version I even tried reinstalling hyper but it didn't help. I tried to install tabby but even it didn't work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Ask on "Ask Ubuntu" or the "Unix & Linux" site.

Comment: It looks like it might be a problem with the `PATH` environment variable ... versus where the `nvm` command was installed.